# I'm trying to get my program to print, but nothing happens when I run it

Tags: java

This code takes two numbers a base, and an integer, and it multiplies it out, but when I try and run it, it takes the numbers, then nothing happens.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RaisedToThePower 
{ 
public static void main(String [] args)

 {

 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

 int base;
 int exponent;
 double x;

 System.out.println("Enter the base");
 base = reader.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Enter the exponent");
 exponent = reader.nextInt();

 x = base^exponent;

 while (exponent > (-1));
{
   System.out.println(x);
  }

 while (exponent <= -1);
  {
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: what is this `x = base^exponent;` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat But oddly, he has two infinite loops, both of which should still be printing.

Comment: Your observations do not agree with the code.  You should be seeing something printing.

Comment: Have you entered any values on the console?

Comment: Dupe? [Whats wrong with this while loop?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2610679)

Answer (score 5):

**Why nothing prints:**

You are not printing anything, since you do

```
while (exponent > (-1)) ;
```

The `;` ends the while statement and since it is an infinite loop you never print anything.

```
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

This is just a statement in a block, which does not belong to the while

To fix this:

```
while (exponent > (-1)) // no ; here
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

This will still be an endless loop, if the exponent is bigger than -1.

The next while has the same problem.

---

**Additional problem:**

```
 x = base^exponent;
```

This does not execute an exponentiation.

`^` is the XOR operator in java. (See [Java Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html))

To get the power of an exponent you need to use:

```
Math.pow(base, exponent);
```

From the java docs:

> Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have ; at end of each while loop  while (exponent > (-1)); And you are not doing anything inside the both loop except printing. Any of the loop get hit it will be infinite loop.

Answer (score -2):

That is not how you get power of a base:

```
x = base ^ exponential;
```

A simple Math.pow example, display 2 to the power of 8.

```
Math.pow(2, 8)
```

[For details](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_pow.htm)

First answer already explains everything.

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to explain why the OP's code is not printing anything.

Comment: There is such thing in Java...`base ^ exponential` is `base exclusive-or exponential`